# Escape DB results using html_escape()

Tags: php, codeigniter, escaping

I have been trying to escape the HTML result from database which is fetched using active record for Codeigniter, and using html_escape() method for the result set which is an array. But some of the models are using result_object and so I am not able to use this method there. How can I overcome this and use html_escape() method for objects also ? Or is there any other way to escape all the values in the object at once ?

Answer (score 1):

In model, it best letting codeigniter create query for you. You can use Codeigniter [Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html).

Model should be like this

```
public function get_data($text) 
{
    $this->db->select('col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4');
    $this->db->from('tabel_a');
    $this->db->where('col_5', $text);

    return $this->db->get();
}
```

In Controller

```
$data['get_data'] = $this->Model->get_data("some text");
```

In View, You can display like this.

```
<?php   
    foreach ($get_data->result() as $row) 
    {   
        echo html_escape($row->col_1);
        echo html_escape($row->col_2);
        echo html_escape($row->col_3);
        echo html_escape($row->col_4);

        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```